# why golang select statement does not randomly choose a case

Tags: select, go, goroutine

This is similar to [go tutorial select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931059/go-tutorial-select-statement), but I didn't get answer from that post. So I asked here. Thanks for answering.

In http://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5, it seems "case c <- x:" is always ready, which means this case will not block select statement.

Based on the sentence "A select blocks until one of its cases can run, then it executes that case. It chooses one at random if multiple are ready.", when "case <-quit:" is also ready, the select statement should randomly choose from "case c <- x:" and "case <-quit:". But the program always go into the "case <-quit:" case.

I also changed the select block to be like below. Then in the first 10 loops, the program randomly print 1-6, but the the program quits once (the 11th output) the quit channel has value 0.

My question is that if the ready cases are randomly selected from, then why the 11th selection is alway the quit case.

```
select {
    case c <- 1:
        x, y = y, x+y
    case c <- 2:
        x, y = y, x+y
    case c <- 3:
        x, y = y, x+y
    case c <- 4:
        x, y = y, x+y
    case c <- 5:
        x, y = y, x+y
    case c <- 6:
        x, y = y, x+y
    case <-quit:
        fmt.Println("quit")
        return
    }
```

Comment: But `c <- x` is *not* ready in the example when `quit` is (based on n the example you linked to). Are you using the same code from the tour?

Comment: @JimB I just understand that the c channel is unbuffered. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the case statements, you're sending values to `c` (e.g `c <- 1`) which blocks until something reads off c as `foo := <- c`. When something writes to `quit` it will hit the case where `<-quit` is at and returning out of the select.

From this example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan struct{})

    go func(q chan<- struct{}) {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        q <- struct{}{}
    }(quit)

    go func(ch chan<- int) {
        var x int
        for range time.Tick(1 * time.Second) {
            c <- x
            x++
        }
    }(c)

    for {
        select {
        case foo := <-c:
            fmt.Println("Foo", foo)
        case bar := <-c:
            fmt.Println("Bar", bar)
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the values randomly printed out on your machine as:

```
$ go run foo.go
Bar 0
Bar 1
Foo 2
Bar 3
quit

$ go run foo.go
Bar 0
Foo 1
Bar 2
Bar 3
quit
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first sentence should be the reason. But the example seems not for the reason. I changed your code to `go func(ch chan<- int) {
        var x int
        for  {
            c <- x
            x++
        }
    }(c)` and `for range time.Tick(1 * time.Second){
        select {`   You can see c <- x is not blocked. For the original codes, I move the q<-0 to another function `go func(q chan<- int) {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        q <- 0
    }(quit)` and try to print <-c in case <- quit, then there will be a deadlock error. So maybe the c<-x only blocks in select statement

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean, mind updating your question with the code you're talking about? `c <- x` will block anywhere, not just in select, unless something is reading off from `c` because c is an unbuffered channel http://play.golang.org/p/3BemJwJjTk

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you're trying this on the go playground, you won't see much randomness since the Playground itself is deterministic.

Comment: Ahhhh, I just get that the c channel is unbuffered. Thanks!